# Insert data into SQL Server from a C# / ASP.NET application

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

This is my first time writing a database insert.

Working on my own and following other people examples I  was able to write this code below.

```
using (SqlConnection openCon = new SqlConnection(""))
{
    String connection = "INSERT INTO Damage (Area,Building,Conference,Apartment,Room,DescribeDamage) VALUES (@Area,@Building,@Conference,@Apartment,@Room,@DescribeDamage)";
    using (SqlCommand CCC = new SqlCommand(connection, openCon))
    {
        try
        {
            openCon.Open();
            CCC.Connection = openCon;
            CCC.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            CCC.Parameters.Add("@Area", SqlDbType.Char, 24).Value = MainDDL.SelectedItem.ToString();
            CCC.Parameters.Add("@Building", SqlDbType.Char, 9).Value = ddlBuildingCCC.SelectedItem.ToString();
            CCC.Parameters.Add("@Conference", SqlDbType.Char, 5).Value = txtConferenceCCC.ToString();
            CCC.Parameters.Add("@Apartment", SqlDbType.VarChar, 4).Value = txtApartmentCCC.ToString();
            CCC.Parameters.Add("@Room", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = txtRoomCCC.ToString();
            CCC.Parameters.Add("@DescribeDamage", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = txtDescribeCCC.ToString();
            CCC.ExecuteNonQuery();
            CCC.Dispose();
        }
        catch (SqlException)
        {
            // error here
        }
        finally
        {
            openCon.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Updated code from Guffa below, i am going to rewrite according to your comments but i want to see if i can get this to work first.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Asset managementConnectionString"))
    {
        String query = "INSERT INTO Damage (Area,Building,Conference,Apartment,Room,DescribeDamage) VALUES (@Area,@Building,@Conference,@Apartment,@Room,@DescribeDamage)";
        using (SqlCommand CCC = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                CCC.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                CCC.Parameters.Add("@Area", SqlDbType.Char, 24).Value = MainDDL.SelectedItem.ToString();
                CCC.Parameters.Add("@Building", SqlDbType.Char, 9).Value = ddlBuildingCCC.SelectedItem.ToString();
                CCC.Parameters.Add("@Conference", SqlDbType.Char, 5).Value = txtConferenceCCC.ToString();
                CCC.Parameters.Add("@Apartment", SqlDbType.VarChar, 4).Value = txtApartmentCCC.ToString();
                CCC.Parameters.Add("@Room", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = txtRoomCCC.ToString();
                CCC.Parameters.Add("@DescribeDamage", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = txtDescribeCCC.ToString();
                CCC.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (SqlException)
            {
                throw; // just rethrow for now
            }
        }
    }


        Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
    }
}
```

I lost the first example i was following along with and haven't been able to find it again.
So I think i am trying two combine two different methods by accident.

**Problem**: 
Right now nothing is debugging but i haven't had anything insert into the database.
I think some of the code isn't needed, can you help me compact the code and getting the data inserting?
I am to the point of rewriting the whole thing again following a different example. But i would like to know why this isn't working for experience.

**UPDATED Problem**, 
Figured out why me error where not getting reported even when i was throwing them. 
Right now i am getting

Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.
on 
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("AssetmanagementConnectionString"))

I haven't been able to figure out the issue. 
What are the steps i can take to figure this out?

Comment: you don't need to call `Dispose` within your `using` block.  It'll do that for you

Comment: Just looking quickly I don't see anything fundamentally wrong.  How are you trying to debug the code?

Comment: What is `txtConferenceCCC` etc - is that a `string`? or a `TextBox`? or...?

Comment: Just for the record: here's the minimal code to do that (here using "dapper" for the `Execute` method): http://pastie.org/8749839 - note the lack of lots of `Dispose()`, `Close()`, `try`, `catch`, `finally` - all of that is redundant and causing you problems

Comment: try this - CCC.Parameters.Add("@Building", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddlBuildingCCC.Text; I have had problems specifying the db datatype this way. And whatever control the params come from just use yourcontrol.Text.

Comment: ok i removed dispose code thanks. Note: txtconferenceCCC is textbox, everything is a textbox expect @area which is a dropdownlist

Comment: so use ddl_yourddl.Text

Comment: whats different from .toString() vs .text or .text.toString()? Which one should i use.

Comment: I figured out why me errors didn't show. Now i am getting the error Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0. For using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("AssetmanagementConnectionString")) any help with this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1. Don't swallow exceptions**

Your code doesn't show any errors because you explicitly swallow any exceptions of type `SqlException`. Remove your `catch` segment or do something meaningful with the exception information.

**2. Name variables properly**

Naming a variable CCC is wrong for a lot of reasons. First, what it represents is unclear and second, in .NET world uppercase suggests a reference to a class member name. Use something like `insertCommand` instead.

**3. Don't dispose an object that's declared in a `using` block.**

Once the `using` block is over the variable will be disposed automatically.

**4. Make sure your connection string isn't a literal, hard-coded string value.**

If you ever need to switch db servers you'll want your connection string at one place so that only one change will be necessary. You can even make it a setting so that no recompiling will be necessary.

**5. Avoid tight coupling**

From the look of it you seem to set your parameter values directly off some UI controls. Don't do that. Instead encapsulate your inserting logic in a class that is independant of the UI, so that it will be easier to reuse it in the future.

That's about everything I can think of right off my head.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you won't need the line CCC.Dispose() because that's the point of the using block - the resource will be disposed after use.

The code looks pretty much OK, apart from this line:

```
CCC.Parameters.Add("@Area", SqlDbType.Char, 80).Value =  80;
```

If you are using a char type and giving it an integer value, an exception will occur.
Since you are swallowing the exception you will not see this error at all hence why no data is inserted.

Change the code to be like below and see if that works:

```
CCC.Parameters.Add("@Area", SqlDbType.Char, 80).Value =  "80";
```

Unless your 'Area' field is actually an integer type in the database. In that case you should change the SqlDbType accordingly.

Comment: That line was actually a test i was trying to do. I was wondering if the the program didn't like how i was trying to assign values dynamically I updated the code above to be what is should actually be.

Comment: To find the issue here you should use the debugger and step through line by line until you hit an exception and check that the variables/objects are what they are supposed to be.

Answer (score 3):

You are right that some code is not needed. But first:

- Never catch an exception and just do nothing about it.

I suppose that you plan to put some error reporting there later, but in the mean time don't leave it as big hole where error messages goes to die. Just rethrow the exception so that you can see what's happening:

```
throw;
```

The `try...catch` block is of course only needed if you actually are going to catch the exception in this method. An alternative is to just omit the `try...catch` and let the exception bubble up and let code at a higher level handle it. It all depends on where you have enough information so that you can do something useful when you handle the exception.

The code that you don't need is:

- As you set the connection when you create the `SqlCommand` object, you don't need to set it again.
- As you are using `using` for both objects, you don't need to dispose the command or close the connection. THe `using` block does that for you.

Also:

- Naming the query `connection` is just confusing. I renamed it `query` and used the `connection` name for the connection instead. (Using a better name for the command variable would also be advisable, but I left it as is in the code to leave it more like your original.)

Revised code:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Asset managementConnectionString")) {
  String query = "INSERT INTO Damage (Area,Building,Conference,Apartment,Room,DescribeDamage) VALUES (@Area,@Building,@Conference,@Apartment,@Room,@DescribeDamage)";
  using (SqlCommand CCC = new SqlCommand(query, connection)) {
    try {
      connection.Open();
      CCC.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

      CCC.Parameters.Add("@Area", SqlDbType.Char, 80).Value =  80;
      CCC.Parameters.Add("@Building", SqlDbType.Char, 9).Value = ddlBuildingCCC.ToString();
      CCC.Parameters.Add("@Conference", SqlDbType.Char, 5).Value = txtConferenceCCC.ToString();
      CCC.Parameters.Add("@Apartment", SqlDbType.VarChar, 4).Value = txtApartmentCCC.ToString();
      CCC.Parameters.Add("@Room", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = txtRoomCCC.ToString();
      CCC.Parameters.Add("@DescribeDamage", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = txtDescribeCCC.ToString();
      CCC.ExecuteNonQuery();
    } catch (SqlException) {
      throw; // just rethrow for now
    }
  }
}
```

There may of couse still be error in the code, for example mismatching data types, but now you should get an error message about it.

Comment: Glad to see a sane re-write; worth making it **very clear** that the `try`/`catch`/`throw` in here is all (as written) technically redundant, though - it isn't something I'd want the OP blindly copying and pasting!

Answer (score 1):

Naming is one thing really important in coding. I was looking to your snippet and the first thing that got my eye is that your `connection` string, I would actually called it command.

```
var cnnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

var command = "INSERT INTO Damage (Area,Building,Conference,Apartment,Room,DescribeDamage) VALUES (@Area,@Building,@Conference,@Apartment,@Room,@DescribeDamage)";

using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(cnnString))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(command, cnn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Area", "80"); // Hardcoded value? Should be an int btw.
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Building", ddlBuildingCCC.ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Conference", ddlBuildingCCC.ToString());
        // ... the other values

        cnn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

You also just need to open the connection before executing the command.